# Lightning performance finding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

This is not a question, but one of my findings after spending some significant time on Lightning framework.

**Problem** : I was querying ~3k accounts and related child objects and was building a wrapper class to return the response back to the lightning app. The code looked something like this

```
Public Class AccountQueryController{

    @AuraEnabled

    Public Static List<AccountWrapper> queryAllAccounts(){

        List<AccountWrapper> accountWrapperList = New List<AccountWrapper>();

        List<Account> myAccounts = [Select id, Name, BillingState.
                                           (Select id
                                              From Contacts)
                                      From Account];

        if(!myAccounts.isEmpty()){
            for(Account currentAccount : myAccounts){
                accountWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper (..) );
            }
        }

        return accountWrapperList;
    }

    Public Class AccountWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        Account currentAccount;

        @AuraEnabled
        Integer noOfContacts;

        @AuraEnabled
        Boolean isPartnerAccount;

        @AuraEnabled
        //Few more variables

        Public AccountWrapper(Account currentAccount, Integer noOfContacts, Boolean isPartnerAccount, ..){
            this.currentAccount = currentAccount;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

It was taking close to 8 Seconds to load the component and which from user experience is quite a lot of time.

**Solution** After exploring chrome JS console for event timelines and SF developer console to understand the server process time for query handling and returning the response, I realised AURA framework was taking a lot of time to create the auraBindings for wrapper class variables. There were plenty of aura statements in the logs.

Just to experiment with the component performance, I decided to modify the response type and return a JSON object string, instead of an object list itself.

To my surprise, it improved the component performance quite significantly and brought it down to ~3 seconds (Which it not too bad).

```
Public Class AccountQueryController{

    @AuraEnabled

    Public Static List<AccountWrapper> queryAllAccounts(){

        List<AccountWrapper> accountWrapperList = New List<AccountWrapper>();

        List<Account> myAccounts = [Select id, Name, BillingState.
                                           (Select id
                                              From Contacts)
                                      From Account];

        if(!myAccounts.isEmpty()){
            for(Account currentAccount : myAccounts){
                accountWrapperList.add(new AccountWrapper (..) );
            }
        }

        return JSON.serialize(accountWrapperList);
    }

    Public Class AccountWrapper{
        Account currentAccount;
        Integer noOfContacts;
        Boolean isPartnerAccount;
        //Few more variables

        Public AccountWrapper(Account currentAccount, Integer noOfContacts, Boolean isPartnerAccount, ..){
            this.currentAccount = currentAccount;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if anybody has faced anything similar. Cheers.

Comment: It might be because of some extra work aura framework has to do for binding. I did not check from performance perspective. Could you please tell how you measured that component is taking 8 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried this in Summer 17 (e.g. a Sandbox?) I hear it's supposed to be much better.

Comment: I used the JS console (Network) to check how long did it take to return the call back. @KiranMachhewar

Comment: After switching to string as response type and JS object at client side, performance has improved drastically @sfdcfox

Answer (score 3):

[Salesforce community optimizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-community-page/alkcnclapbnefkodhbkpifdkceldogka) chrome plugin can actually breakup and help identify slowness in your components. On Server calls there is a section other which can help tell how much time it takes to serialize return type of your aura enabled class method.

1. Salesforce did a review of our code and they said
   `List<SrappperClasses>` is causing high serializing and de-serializing
   time.They asked us to send sObject instances with just relevant
   fields and manipulate UI using a java script object
2. Also if your markup contains lot of custom labels(>100) it increases the overall serialization time. they asked to load the entire set of labels as a map and refer that in lightning components instead of directly referring them in markups using labels.